# Can I Insert a Javascript Array to my PHP form?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

Long story short:
I have a long list of check boxes for adding options to a purchase (TV, Radio, Stove, etc.)

Now I need to insert a LogIn form When they hit next (cut down on the number of quotes created/stored with no customer contact info).
But I was loosing all the options selected and would have to make the customer input again.

So I added an on-click - add to array function for the option id's selected. So that I could collect the ID's before submitting form.

Now the problem... How to send that array to the server with the php form, and I am way to new to Java.

In my research - I can either add the array values to the form action ?optionids=34,891,679,etc
Ugly but O.K.
What I would like is ... If this makes sense.. on-click of next button document.write

My code so far: (in )

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var numArray = [];
    function addToArray(num){
        numArray.push(num);
        document.getElementById("pTxt").innerHTML = numArray;
        return false;

    }
 </script>
 <script>
    function jstophp(){
        var javavar=document.getElementById("pTxt").value;  
        document.getElementById("rslt").innerHTML="<?php 
        $phpvar='"+javavar+"'; 
        echo $phpvar;?>";
    }
</script>
```

I can see the values go in at

```
<div id="pTxt"></div>
```

But I can't pull them back out.

Any advice?

Comment: `.innerHTML=""+javavar+""` is not exactly legal javascript...

Comment: You can use JSON, can be converted to an PHP object or an array. use the json_encode en json_decode PHP functions for JSON in PHP.

Comment: Why don’t you simple save the choices in the server-side session when the form is submitted …?

Comment: I found that +javavar+ while researching... all I ever got from the variable was "+javavar" or "undefined".

Comment: I read on JSON - don't really see that helping.. I need to get the variables hidden in <div id=pTxt> to a html input field.

Comment: how about populating the values in your form by using <input type="hidden">?

Answer (score 0):

You should name your html inputs so that they become an array automatically in the $_POST

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options[tv]" value="tv">
<input type="checkbox" name="options[radio]" value="radio">
<input type="checkbox" name="options[stove]" value="stove">
```

Your $_POST will look something like:

```
options => 
    tv => tv, 
    radio => radio 
    ...
```

If that is not an option, use a hidden input element rather than a DIV to store your array:

```
<input type="hidden" id="pTxt" name="idList">
<script>
    var numArray = [];
    function addToArray(num){
        numArray.push(num);
        document.getElementById("pTxt").value = numArray;
        return false;

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Yeay, that's how it used to work before I was told to insert a login form.

Comment: ok, updated the code. You can just save what you have in a hidden input.

Comment: Sorry, Still no good. I figure it is because the login form is an include - and written to the screen before anything is added to the array?  I can put the <div> on the page and see id get added, but when I put the div in the include - stays empty. Hit submit on the form... no data.

Comment: You have some other problem then. There should be no difference. If you can populate a div, you can populate a hidden input. Without seeing your full code, it's not possible to know where you're going wrong. But you have something somewhere that you're missing. If you're populating the DIV when the form submits, then as long as your input is inside your form tag, it should populate and contain what you want. If it's not doing that, you have another problem you haven't spotted yet.